# How to move view for keyboard in portrait orientations

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I have an app that runs in portrait and portraitUpsideDown only.  I need to push the view up when the keyboard appears and pull it back down when it disappears.  The following code works perfectly if the device stays in portrait, but if it is in portraitUpsideDown the view moves the wrong direction (-260 instead of 260), plus if the orientation changes while the keyboard is showing, it's not handled...  The keyboardWillHide method works fine in both orientations.  Is there a way to move the view RELATIVE to the keyboard or status bar so it doesn't matter what orientation the device is in???

```
- (void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSLog(@"Keyboard Will Show");
    double animationDuration;
    animationDuration = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y + -260);
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
    }];
}

- (void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    double animationDuration;
    animationDuration = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    NSLog(@"Keyboard Will Hide");

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
     }completion:^(BOOL finished){
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it (less than elegantly) this way:

NOTE:  Things you SHOULD do, and I will change this code to do them eventually are:  create a property to hold the keyboard animation duration so I can use it outside of the keyboard delegate methods, and similarly create a property for the offset and determine it using the userInfo for the height of the keyboard.

```
- (void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSLog(@"Keyboard Will Show");
    if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        offset = -260;
    else 
        offset = 260;

    double animationDuration;
    animationDuration = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y + offset);
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
    }];
}

- (void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    double animationDuration;
    animationDuration = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    NSLog(@"Keyboard Will Hide");

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y - offset);
     }completion:^(BOOL finished){
    }];
}

- (void) keyboardDidShow
{
    NSLog(@"Keyboard Did Show");
    keyboardIsShowing = YES;
}

- (void) keyboardDidHide
{
    NSLog(@"Keyboard Did Hide");
    keyboardIsShowing = NO;
}


-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{    
    if (keyboardIsShowing && UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation))
    {
        if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait && offset == 260)
            offset = -260;
        else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown && offset == -260)
            offset = 260;
        else 
            return;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y + 2* offset);
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much what I had to do in my apps. One test case to make sure works is activating the keyboard, turning the device over, and then dismissing the keyboard. It looks like you have that covered though.

Comment: It just seems like there would be an easier or at least more elegant way of doing it... guess not... this works...  I can't imagine the pain if this app supported all orientations...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will have to manage this yourself. You can interrogate the current orientation and set your y-axis adjustment appropriately.

```
int movementDistance = -260;
if (UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown == [self interfaceOrientation]) movementDistance = -movementDistance;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the frame height, or set the contentInset for the view, not the center.

Comment: The issue is the same if I use the frame height, have to know whether to add or subtract...